# SQL Select DISTINCT with WHERE LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, distinct, sql-server-2016

I am trying to select distinct BILLCOMPANY from a table with a where BILLCOMPANY like 'value' however it's returning all matches not just distinct.

Suggestions?

```
SELECT DISTINCT BillCompany,  UniqueID
From Customer
WHERE BillCompany LIKE  <cfqueryparam value="%#URL.term#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
```

Sample Data
UniqueID / SiteCompany   /  BillingCompany
1     /    McDonalds-213 / ABC Management
2     /    McDonalds-215 /  XYZ Company
3    /    McDonalds-817  / ABC Management
4     /    Burger King-6 /  XYZ Company
5     /    Dairy Queen-7 /  Billy Bob Corp
6     /    KFC-4857   /    ABC Management

In the end I need a list:
ABC Management
XYZ Company
Billy Bob Corp

UniqueID is going to be used later to pull the rest of the billing address.

Comment: Remove `UniqueID`.

Comment: I need UniqueID in my results though...

Comment: `DISTINCT BillCompany,  UniqueID` means unique pairs of the 2 columns and not unique `UniqueID`

Comment: Could you add sample data and your expected results to the question?

Comment: I make a broad assumption here that `UniqueID` is unique for an Customer?  Thus, as you have it you get ALL of them since it being different for every customer you get all the customer values for that, yet you state "I need UniqueID in my results though" - OK, so you did that. Now add clarification by perhaps posting a sample set of output here.

Comment: UniqueID refers to the SiteCompany.

Comment: so, in the sample data and results you gave, which `UniqueID` would you put with "ABC Management"?

Comment: Any of the UniqueID's would work. I didn't build the original database. Stupidly ABC's address is the same in hundreds of records. It should have been designed so Site info and Billing info were two different tables and linked with an identifier. I'm updating it so instead of the user having to re-enter the info for ABC it auto-populates based on previous entries. In hindsight the comment about removing UniqueID from the SQL is the answer - I can match on BillCompany. (Blond Moment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT BillCompany,  MIN(UniqueID) AS UniqueID  -- here should be business logic min/max
From Customer
WHERE BillCompany LIKE  <cfqueryparam value="%#URL.term#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
GROUP BY BillCompany
```

Answer (score 1):

I was overthinking this. I don't need UniqueID. In the next step, I can match on BillCompany instead of the ID.